# Javascript - Running variables through switch statement in order

Tags: javascript, loops, switch-statement, vuejs2

I am trying to get certain api calls to run in the proper order. The user selects the months they choose to run (ex. Oct, Nov, Dec). I am trying to get them to fire in order. Oct, Nov, Dec(not Dec,Oct, Nov)

The first function is an If statement if the whole array is present I can get it to run in order just fine, its when they start adjusting it that I can not keep the order straight.

So the getStationsInOrder works fine with callbacks - but I can't seem to get the loop to send the months to the switch in the proper order. I have removed return from the switch so it does not just end with the month is first in array

example. User Selects only November, December, January - trigger those api calls in order. the months are in an array passed to a for loop then, the loop passes it to the switch.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
noaaData: function () {
         console.log(this.checkedMonths, 'Months Selected')
            //if all checked get all data, array smaller than 7 get 
selected stations

            if (!this.checkedMonths || this.checkedMonths.length == 7){ 
                 //trigger this function - runs api.get's in order

                this.getStationsInOrder(this.userFIPS, function(){
                console.log('Done here move on')
                })

            } else {
  //this does NOT run in order - there by messing up all other equations 

                this.getStationsChecked(this.userFIPS)

            }//end else
     },

getStationsChecked: function (userFIPS){
          for (var i = 0; i < this.checkedMonths.length; i++) {
                console.log(this.checkedMonths[i], 'month in ooop')

         switch (this.checkedMonths[i]) {
            case 'October':
                this.getStationsOct(userFIPS)
            break;

            case 'November':
                  this.getStationsNov(userFIPS)
                  console.log('nov')
            break;

            case 'December':
                  this.getStationsDec(userFIPS)
                  console.log('dec')
            break;
            case 'January':
                  this.getStationsJan(userFIPS)
                  console.log('jan')
            break;
            case 'February':
                  this.getStationsFeb(userFIPS)
                  console.log('feb')
            break;
            case 'March':
                  this.getStationsMar(userFIPS)
                  console.log('mar')
            break;
            case 'April':
                this.getStationsApr(userFIPS)
                 console.log('apr')
            break;

            default: 'Error getStationsChecked default case'
         } 
          }
     },
     getStationsInOrder: function(userFIPS, callback){ 
         self = this
// series of callbacks to run each in order - oct thru 
    // April - triggered in if statement in noaaData() 

                 self.getStationsOct(userFIPS, function(){
                        self.getStationsNov(userFIPS, function(){
                            self.getStationsDec(userFIPS, function(){
                                self.getStationsJan(userFIPS, function(){
                                    self.getStationsFeb(userFIPS,  function (){
                                        self.getStationsMar(userFIPS, function(){
                                            self.getStationsApr(userFIPS, callback)
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
     },
```

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of your intended goal, I would recommend leveraging the classes and the `done` or `completed` methods of the callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1: Chaining Promises

The core of the problem is how to make sure the data is presented in the right order, so one way to achieve it is by chaining promises and make sure they resolve in the right order.

### Demo: forEach

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const createPromise = (number) => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + number
   return () => fetch(url)
}

const promises = numbers.map((number) => createPromise(number))

let dummyPromise = Promise.resolve();
promises.forEach((promise) => {
    dummyPromise = dummyPromise
        .then(() => promise())
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => { console.log(result) })
})
```

### Demo: reduce

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const createPromise = (number) => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + number
   return () => fetch(url)
}

const promises = numbers.map((number) => createPromise(number))

promises.reduce((acc, promise) => acc
    .then(() => promise())
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => { console.log(result) })
, Promise.resolve())
```

### Vue Demo:

You can try this code snippet, or check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kevlai22/pen/boLQNv?editors=1010), you can compare the order of the data by referring to the `id`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    months: { Jan: 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3, Apr: 4, May: 5, Jun: 6, Jul: 7, Aug: 8, Sep: 9, Oct: 10, Nov: 11, Dec: 12},
    availableMonths: [
      { month: 'Jan', selected: false }, { month: 'Feb', selected: false }, { month: 'Mar', selected: false },
      { month: 'Apr', selected: false }, { month: 'May', selected: false }, { month: 'Jun', selected: false },
      { month: 'Jul', selected: false }, { month: 'Aug', selected: false }, { month: 'Sep', selected: false },
      { month: 'Oct', selected: false }, { month: 'Nov', selected: false }, { month: 'Dec', selected: false },
    ],
    retrievedData: []
  },
  methods: {
     // helper method for constructing API url
     getMonthNumber(month) { return this.months[month] },
     // this method returns a function that will return a promise for fetching data
     getFromApiByMonth(month) {
       const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.getMonthNumber(month)
       return () => fetch(url)
     },
     // method for getting all the data
     getAllData() {
       // making sure data will be retrieved in order
       this.retrievedData = []
       const promises = this.availableMonths
        .filter((item) => item.selected)
        .map((item) => this.getFromApiByMonth(item.month))
       
       if (promises.length > 0) {
         // let dummyPromise = Promise.resolve();
         // promises.forEach((promise) => {
         //   dummyPromise = dummyPromise
         //     .then(() => promise())
         //     .then((res) => res.json())
         //     .then((result) => { this.retrievedData.push(result) })
         // })  
         promises.reduce((acc, promise) => acc
             .then(() => promise())
             .then((res) => res.json())
             .then((result) => { this.retrievedData.push(result) })
         , Promise.resolve())
       }
     }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getAllData()">Get Data</button>
    <div v-for="item in availableMonths">
      {{item.month}}<input v-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" v-model="toggle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>   
    <ul v-for="data in retrievedData">
      <li>{{data}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Method 2: RxJS (Observable)

As you can see, promise though great, chaining promises is still hard at times. If you've used Angular 2 before, then you heard of Observables before.  Therefore, whenever I need to chain promises, I use RxJS instead, which I treat promises as 'stream' and **concat** them altogether (if I don't care about order, I can use **merge**), it's easier for error handling and caters to better code readability. You can learn more about RxJS and Observables [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs). Also, note that Observable will be included in ES8.

### Demo:

```js
let retrievedData = []
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
const streams = numbers
    .map((number) => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+number)
    .map((url) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
        fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    ))

// every promise now becomes a stream
// concat all the streams together
const stream = Rx.Observable.concat(...streams)

// subscribe is like start watching a  YouTube video, 
// which keeps emitting values until the stream is complete
stream.subscribe(
    // for every result emitted from stream
    (result) => retrievedData.push(result),
    // error handling
    (err) => console.log(err),
    // when the stream is complete
    () => console.log(retrievedData)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

### Vue Demo:

You can try this code snippet, or check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kevlai22/pen/vedbWN?editors=1010):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    months: { Jan: 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3, Apr: 4, May: 5, Jun: 6, Jul: 7, Aug: 8, Sep: 9, Oct: 10, Nov: 11, Dec: 12},
    availableMonths: [
      { month: 'Jan', selected: false }, { month: 'Feb', selected: false }, { month: 'Mar', selected: false },
      { month: 'Apr', selected: false }, { month: 'May', selected: false }, { month: 'Jun', selected: false },
      { month: 'Jul', selected: false }, { month: 'Aug', selected: false }, { month: 'Sep', selected: false },
      { month: 'Oct', selected: false }, { month: 'Nov', selected: false }, { month: 'Dec', selected: false },
    ],
    retrievedData: []
  },
  methods: {
     // helper method for constructing API url
     getMonthNumber(month) { return this.months[month] },
     // this method returns a function that will return a promise for fetching data
     getFromApiByMonth(month) {
       const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.getMonthNumber(month)
       return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
         fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
       )
     },
     // method for getting all the data
     getAllData() {
       // making sure data will be retrieved in order
       this.retrievedData = []
       const streams = this.availableMonths
        .filter((item) => item.selected)
        .map((item) => this.getFromApiByMonth(item.month))
       
       if (streams.length > 0) {
         const stream = Rx.Observable.concat(...streams)
         stream.subscribe(        
           (result) => this.retrievedData.push(result),
           err => console.log(err),
           () => console.log('Fetching Complete!')
         )
       }
     }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.3/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getAllData()">Get Data</button>
    <div v-for="item in availableMonths">
      {{item.month}}<input v-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" v-model="toggle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>   
    <ul v-for="data in retrievedData">
      <li>{{data}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

A simple example:

```
let callNumber   = 0;
let timeoutSpeed = 5000;

function AsyncMocker(resolve)
{
    callNumber    = ++callNumber;
    timeoutSpeed -= 500;

    return new Promise(function(resolve)
    {
        //  simulate asynchronous behaviour.
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            console.log('Async task has been completed from call number: ' + callNumber);

            //  tell the promise that the async work is done.
            resolve();
        }, timeoutSpeed);
    });
}

AsyncMocker().then(AsyncMocker)
             .then(AsyncMocker)
             .then(AsyncMocker)
             .then(AsyncMocker)
             .then(AsyncMocker)
             .then(AsyncMocker)
             .then(AsyncMocker);
```